# Inserting USB drive into netbook using 11.10 activates movie player

Tags: 11.10, usb

When I insert a memory stick into my Samsung N150Plus netbook using 11.10, instead of File Manager opening (as happened previously), now Movie Player opens up. Where is the setting to change the default application that opens when a memory stick is inserted? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no USB option in removable media, its all CD and DVD etc so I set it to 'never start or prompt programs on insertion of media', at least the stops movie player starting up. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Click the gear/power icon in the top right, select 'System Settings...', click 'Removable Media', and change the appropriate setting, to the appropriate option.